# Prove the sequence $1, 2, 3\ldots$ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. I want to prove that it does not converge. It is obviously inherently correct I just don't know how to approach the proof. With each $n \gt N$ the sequence, $\{n\}$ continues to get larger and larger. So for ${n}_n: n_1 \lt n_2 \lt n_3.....$ This goes on till infinity

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I prove $\{n\}_n$ does not converge

Comment: I edited the post for clarity and legibility, but took some creative freedoms. Feel free to edit it if you disagree with the changes. I'll also note that, in my experience, sequences are written as $(n_i)_{i=1}^\infty$. The braces $\{\}$ denote sets.

Comment: What's you definition of $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges?  If you write that out and apply $\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to it can you see it fails.

Comment: If a sequence converges, then it is bounded. Since $a_{n} = n$ is not bounded, it does not converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write out the definition of converge:

$a_n \to k$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $N$ so that if $n > N$ then $|a_n - k| <\epsilon$.

So is that true for $\{n\}$?

Suppose $n\to k$ and let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then there is an $N$ so that for all $n > N$ we have $|n-k| < \epsilon$.

That is to say that $-\epsilon < n-k < \epsilon$ or $k-\epsilon < n < k+\epsilon$ for *all* $n > N$.

...????....

Well, just pick an $n > \max(N, k+\epsilon)$ and this is obviously not true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to negate the definition of what it means for a sequence $a_n$ to converge to a limit $L$. The definition of convergence is: for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

The negation says for *every* $L$, there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $N$, there exists $n >N$ such that $|a_n-L| \geq \epsilon$. That's a lot of quantifiers, but essentially what you have to prove is that no matter what "candidate" limit $L$ you choose, the sequence $a_n=n$ cannot converge to $L$, because no matter how far out you go in the sequence there will be points far from $L$. Now try to make that intuition into a rigorous proof using the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence isn't Cauchy:  $\forall N,\exists m\neq n\ge N$ with $\mid x_m-x_n\mid=m-n\ge1$.  $\therefore $ it doesn't converge.